# R error: Error in heuristic_models , index out of bounds

Tags: r

I am trying to run some models for attribution modelling:

My input is like this:

My code is

```
Data = read.csv("agg_attribution_model_input_90days_201709281041.csv")

> Data
   path.total_conversions.total_conversion_value.total_null.assigned_cost
    1    4905call > 4767call;1;322.799987793;1;53.1883528852
    2    call > 9530call > 9530call > 1761mail;1;720;1;0
    3    9599call;1;924.4400024414;1;48.162603373
    4    3944mail > 1345mail > 9532call > 3944mail > 1345mail > 9533call > 9530call > 9533call > 9530call > 4915call;1;360;1;0

> library(ChannelAttribution)
> library(reshape)
> library(ggplot2)
> H <- heuristic_models(Data, 'path', 'total_conversions', var_value='total_conversion_value')
Error in heuristic_models(Data, "path", "total_conversions", var_value = "total_conversion_value") : 
  index out of bounds
```

I guess it's reading my file somehow wrong? I am new to R and I couldn't find something to help me on this.. 
Any ideas?

Comment: index out of bounds error means you are accessing row/column that does not exist. For example, lets say you have 10 rows in your data but you are accessing 11th row then code will throw an error index out of bounds. In your case, I suggest you check your data in your csv file and also check your data frame Data.

Comment: You were right, it was simple actually :) Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The error appears because you are using your current index in the heuristic model, what it is not available.

Really, you should add a new index just for running properly that method. In my case, it is worked.